# Store data in a VueJS mixin

Tags: vue.js, components, mixins, vue-mixin

I want to create a VueJS mixin that adds a couple of methods to the parent. In order to do this I need to store some data too.

Is it possible to store data in a mixin that can be accessed by a component that uses the mixin?

Answer (score 2):

You should use some [centralised state mechanism](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch) or more popular option [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) to store the data and manipulate it from the methods of mixin.